# Declare type of extended abstract class in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, inheritance, types

I have an abstract base class and I have extended classes to actually implement the abstract methods. In a function, I add objects from the extended base class to a js object.

```
abstract class BaseClass {
    abstract fun(): void;
}

class ExtendedClassA extends BaseClass {
    fun(): void {
        console.log("Class A");
    }
}

class ExtendedClassB extends BaseClass {
    fun(): void {
        console.log("Class B");
    }
}

type ExtendedObjects = { [name: string]: BaseClass };
type ExtendedClasses =  { [name: string]: BaseClass };

const extendedObjects: ExtendedObjects= {}
const extendedClasses: ExtendedClasses = { A: ExtendedClassA, B: ExtendedClassB }

function initializeBaseObject(key: string): void {
   extendedObjects[key] = new extendedClasses[key];
}

initializeBaseObject("A");
initializeBaseObject("B")

extendedObjects["A"].fun();
extendedObjects["B"].fun();
```

TypeScript throws the following error:

***"This expression is not constructible. Type 'BaseClass ' has no construct signatures."***

It is no surprise since BaseClass is an abstract class.
I can overcome this error by intersecting any with the BaseClass.

```
type ExtendedObjects = { [name: string]: any & BaseClass };
type ExtendedClasses =  { [name: string]: any & BaseClass };
```

I don't really like this approach since I prefer not to use "any" if possible.
In the actual code, the extended classes are in a different module.
**I don't know which classes are in the "extendedClass" object.**
I only know that the extended classes are the inheritance of the base class.
What other choices do I have?

Edit1: The example is now working. [TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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)

Edit2: Added extends BaseClass

Comment: I think some details are missing from the types above, and if I try to take reasonable guesses at them, I don't have much luck. Please update the question with a [mre] (ideally also including a link to the same code on [the TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play)) to help people help you.

Answer (score 0):

I can see no relation between `ExtendedClassA` and `BaseClass` so you have to add:

```js
class ExtendedClassA extends BaseClass {
```

the same with `ExtendedClassB`

also, if I were you, I would not define type `ExtendedClasses`; I would create a `const` and then create type from it:

```js
const extendedClasses = { A: ExtendedClassA, B: ExtendedClassB };

type ExtendedClasses = typeof extendedClasses;
```

then, you have to fix your method's signature, because `string` is too generic to use it as object's key:

```js
function initializeBaseObject(key: keyof ExtendedClasses): void {
```

Here is [TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgQmgpgYVXQQG8AoBChUSGeBAMwFcA7ACgEoAuBANwHsAlgBMA3KQC%20pUijQYAogA8IOZkJxCCsgIIIcSlUIzYw%20QhjKUGLDt37CS5S5Vh9mYPshwA6ZHwDmrABEmkRagexilpKS0mYIisqq6iFgmLr6qka4KQ6WTGxcvIJCuU4ULm4e3r4BwXGY4ZGU0VIQAJ4ADjjxGWpCAPIgAFY48BgAvCQIANrMwAC2ONw0Asx%20ALrcxqayCOJi0q6Q6Yl9gyNj3AkG6uejEGCTxJIVx3qnyWY4E1NaV72fbQAGiw-w%20GjMaX2pHaXR64JS3wQk1hOD49BONwhsm%20B3y8AErgQqwEEAEwGQAgAXjhtnd4KwANY4NrcZltdHwrGIsCFOwlCwUd5Y%20kPabs9bIhDMHAAd0xSWx6G%204pZ6zEMRJZIp1NpuFFQTCEVIWvJlJpdOG9yCDXYUmFitFYGmgTC6y8%20Q4YgdZytYxdDXdnoiQA).

Comment: I forgot to add extends. In the original code, it's actually there. I can create a type from an existing object. The classes are added dynamically.